# How config Exim accept email form other server

Tags: config, exim

I am trying config Exim to accept email sent from an other server, but I can not.
On my server, I can sent email to local user:

```
# echo "This is test 1." | mail -s Testing_1 user_a@mydomain.com
```

so i want send an email to user_a (with add: user_a@mydomain.com) from other domain (eg: gmail, yahoo)

I try sent an email from gmail account to user_a@mydomain.com, so check exim log (`/var/log/exim_mainlog`) nothing here?
maybe this email can't sent to my server with @mydomain.com . Or Exim can't receive any email?

os: CentOs, dedicated!

Comment: Add to your description the results of:  1. exim -bt user_a@mydomain.com    2. exim -bP '+local_domains'    Those two commands should give us a better view of your system, assuming you use standard +local_domains domain list.

Comment: #exim -bt user_a@mydomain.com
LOG: MAIN PANIC Failed to find user "system" from expanded string "${lookup{$domain}lsearch* {/etc/userdomains}{$value}}" for the has_alias_but_no_mailbox_discarded_to_prevent_loop router
user_a@mydomain.com cannot be resolved at this time: Failed to find user "system" from expanded string "${lookup{$domain}lsearch* {/etc/userdomains}{$value}}" for the has_alias_but_no_mailbox_discarded_to_prevent_loop router
    <-- user_a@mydomain.com user_a@as.mydomain.com    <-- user_a@mydomain.com  <-- user_a@mydomain.com   router = localuser, transport = local_delivery

Comment: AND: #exim -bP '+local_domains'  domainlist local_domains = lsearch;/etc/localdomains  when i view /etc/localdomains ->  mydomain.com exist here. /etc/userdomain ->  mydomain.com: system   and  *: nobody . tell me how config ? sorry, i am newbie.

Comment: In the future, edit the original question and put the output of those commands there, not as a comment. In the original question portion, you can control the formatting, whereas in a comment all of the output gets mashed together.

Answer (score 0):

Many times when you have a problem with exim, you can simply Google the word "exim" and the error message to find others who have had the same problem.  Most of the time, whatever you find will be someone asking nearly the question as you in a webhosting forum and the fix for it later in the same thread.  I searched for *exim  Failed to find user "system" from expanded string* and found the [full thread](http://forums.cpanel.net/f43/failed-find-user-system-expanded-string-lookup-domain-lsearch-153985.html) and the [exact answer](http://forums.cpanel.net/f43/failed-find-user-system-expanded-string-lookup-domain-lsearch-153985.html#post648913) further down in that discussion.

Based on the results of that discussion thread, you appear to be using CPanel and its custom Exim configuration.  Per the instruction in that thread, fix the entries in your **/etc/userdomains** and that problem will go away.